# How to prep this concrete shower floor for a replacement acrylic base?

Tags: bathroom, concrete, shower, self-leveling-concrete

Ripped out a shower surround, replacing with new wall panels and shower pan. The prior pan was set in some cement or thinset, and that's left a very uneven surface. How do I prep it for the replacement base? I suspect chiseling it out will be difficult and still leave it too uneven. So I'm thinking a self leveling compound, followed after dry with thinset to secure the new pan. Seeking recommended compounds and techniques.

Also, should I remove the curb, or find a pan that will fit over it? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Self-leveling compound will, well, level itself and that's not really good for water drainage. You want to be able to shape it to ensure you've got a slight slope toward the drain so the water drains out of the pan. I'm not 100% sure what the right answer is, but SLC is the wrong answer.

Comment: @FreeMan - thanks. Putting a prefab shower pan in that location, which needs a level substrate. So seems I either need to remove material, or add material. I was thinking SLC would be the best/easiest way to make a flat level place to insert the pan.

Comment: I missed the part about putting a new pan in. If the pan itself is sloped and requires a level base, LSC does seem appropriate. However, I'm not an expert. I'm surprised nobody else has chimed in on this yet.